# how to set default style from particular workspace using gsconfig?

Tags: geoserver, style, geoserver-rest-api

I'm able to set default style for any layer using below code

`cat = Catalog("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest", "admin", "geoserver")

layer = cat.get_layer("layer_name")

layer._set_default_style("style_name")

cat.save(layer)`

Now I want to set default style from particula workspace (say states),How I can able to do?
I tried as

`cat = Catalog("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest", "admin", "geoserver")

layer = cat.get_layer("layer_name")

layer._set_default_style("states","style_name")

cat.save(layer)`

The error is: TypeError:_set_default_style() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given).

Answer (score 3):

you can do:

```
my_style = 'my_ws:my_style'
style = cat.get_style(my_style)
layer = cat.get_layer('layername')
layer.default_style = style
cat.save(layer)
```

Comment: Is there a way to set an alternate style as well?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess here, but you might be able to set a style from a particular workspace by appending the workspace, then a colon, then the style name.  E.g.:

layer._set_default_style("states:style_name")